# Can anyone explain me on how to form regular expression and explain this regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
```

1. Replace is a method
2. What does / indicate?
3. What does ^ indicate along with 0-9
4. What does /g indicate?

Do we need to start a regular expression with / or can we start with anything?

Comment: here is for all future Regex related queries: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Comment: The code above eliminate non-numeric characters.

Comment: Isn't there one close parenthesis too many here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/` introduces a *regular expression literal* (just like `"` and `'` introduce string literals). A regular expression literal is in the form `/expression/flags`, where `expression` is the body of the expression, and `flags` are optional flags (`i` for case-insensitive, `g` for global, `m` for multi-line stuff).

The `^` as the first character within `[]` means any character ***not*** matching the following. So `[^0-9]` means "any character except `0` through `9`".

The `/g` ends the regular expression literal and includes the "global" flag on it. Without the `g`, `replace` would only replace the first match, not all of them.

In all, what that does is replace any character that isn't `0` through `9` with a blank — e.g., removes non-digits. It could be written more simply as:

```
var result = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

...because `\D` (note that's an upper-case `D`) means "non-digit".

MDC has [a decent page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp) on regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The / and / are the start and end of the regex pattern, the g mean global (anything after the 2nd / is an optional modifier for the regex).

^ means not.

So in this case it'll remove any character that isn't a number.

Comment: I agree. For a user who obviously doesn't understand the basics of regex, regular-expressions.info is much better. They would get lost in W3School's site.

Comment: Fair enough, removed the link. The mozilla one you posted does look better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. See the manual for [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
2. See [regular expression literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression)
3. See [using special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#section_4)
4. See [searching with flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)

Answer (score 1):

1. replace is method of string type
2. / / indicates there's a regular expression inside of them
3. ^ inside [] means "not"
4. "g" means to replace globally

regular expressions in javascript should put in to a pair of "/"

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) W3 Schools tutorial should cover most of the basics. [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) other tutorial covers the flasg, such as `/g` which can be passed to the regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes
2. start and end of regex
3. not, that just basically means, match any non-integer
4. global replacement, the effect of not having that is replacement only done for the first encounter.

At least in javascript, yes you have to use /.

Answer (score 0):

/ indicates the beginning and end of the regexp. Hence in your case [^0-9]  is the regex.
^ indicates the start of line
/g indicates the substitution to take place for all the match - globl, and not only for the first match.

Comment: ^ here is not used as an anchor, it means a character other than what is in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

/g enables "global" matching. When using the replace() method, specify this modifier to replace all matches, rather than only the first one.

/ start regex

^ match except  the symbols 0-9

Answer (score 0):

**What it does:** Removes all non-numeric (0-9) characters.

- The forward slash (/) is used when you declare RegExp literals
- The [^0-9] means any character OTHER THAN 0-9. The ^ means "other than". You can remove it and it'll look for only a character 0-9.
- The /g represents global replacement.

So this will look for any non-number character and replace it with nothing.
As Shamim notes, regular-expressions.info/is a great site. Best of luck!

You can try out javascript regex's on this site: http://regexpal.com/
Couples with http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial, it's a great resource for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as to creating one, this forum is not the best for that -- it is a rather large question, best left to [one of the best resources on RegExp that I know of](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

It looks like you're in JS, so:

- replace is a method of String. It replaces the provided expression with the second string, in this case nothing.
- In JavaScript `/` must begin and end all RegEx's, all `/` in the middle must be escaped with a `\` (so they look like this: `\/`). In other languages (PHP, Perl being some of the most prominent), you can use other characters such as `~` and `#`.
- `^` inside of `[]` means negation, `-` means range, so `[^0-9]` means "not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9" `[0-9]` does have a shorthand of `\d`. So `/[^\d]/g` is a valid, alternate way to say the same thing.
- `/g` means "global" as in "match all incidents, not just the first.

Your expression means, "replace all non-digits with nothing".

Answer (score 0):

The / encapsulate your pattern (you need to escape / with \ if you want to use it in pattern)
and the trailing character after the slashes are modifiers. 'g' in this case means global search (i.e. find all matches)

^ is negation.. [0-9] is range indicating all numbers from 0 to 9.
so [^0-9] means anything except numbers
So This regex basically replaces anything except numbers in the string with '' (i.e. remove them)

Regex has lots of other features, you should research them!